# SQL / Postgres SELECT, ORDER BY smallest ratio within a GROUP

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `Product`s model, and each product has 1 or more `Sku`s.  Each sku has a `shipping_price` and a `selling_price`.

I'd like to sort the products by their skus' highest or lowest ratio of `shipping_price/selling_price`, but I'm having trouble getting the query right. For example, for the "minimum shipping ratio" right now I have:

```
SELECT 
  p.id, 
  p.title, 
  array_agg(s.shipping_price) as shipping_prices, 
  array_agg(s.baseline_price) as baseline_prices, 
  min(s.shipping_price/s.baseline_price) as shipping 
FROM "Products" p 
JOIN "Skus" s 
ON p.id = s.product_id 
WHERE p.category_id in (1,2,3) 
GROUP BY p.id 
ORDER BY shipping ASC 
LIMIT 48 
OFFSET 0;
```

But this gives a lot of zeros for `shipping` where they clearly aren't zeros.  It looks like I need some combination of array operations and min, but I'm not sure how to combine the methods [HERE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html).

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the type is preserved by `min`, so dividing an integer by another integer rounds everything down to zero.

Solution was to cast to a double:

```
min(s.shipping_price*1.0/s.baseline_price) as shipping
```